# true or false switch statement in php

Tags: php

Why is the below code printing out both "yes" and! "no" ?

Only if I add 'break;' to the **TRUE** case, it only prints out "yes" , but that shouldnt change the fact that the case **FALSE**, is not going to run, $arr is always an array.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
$arr=[1,2];
switch (is_array($arr)) {
    case TRUE:
        print "yes";
        //break;
    case FALSE:
        print "no";
}
```

Comment: `switch` was designed to work this way. It will execute all code going through all subsequent cases until a `break;`  (or `return`). This is the case in all the programming languages that include this construct that are meant to be "C like" (because C is where this behaviour originates from). This is not for example the case for "Pascal like" languages. PHP is very much influenced by C so it retains this behaviour

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php - _"PHP continues to execute the statements until the end of the switch block, or the first time it sees a break statement. **If you don't write a break statement at the end of a case's statement list, PHP will go on executing the statements of the following case.**"_ - When in doubt, always start with the manual - and read it thoroughly.

Comment: thanks both of you. seem i misunderstood the use of switch.

Comment: Your code might just been an example while testing, but if not (or if someone else planned for it), then using switch/case for a simple boolean check is overkill. The above switch/case could for example be replaced with one line: `print is_array($array) ? 'yes' : 'no';`.

Answer (score -1):

Well... the `switch` statement requires a `break` after each case, since by default it'll will try to execute the next `case`; as said on [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/pHp/php_switch.asp) :

> If there is a match, the block of code associated with that case is
> executed. Use break to prevent the code from running into the next
> case automatically.

Now about the expected return value, the condition will return a boolean indeed, but not in the `ALPHA` format, but rather in a `NUMERIC boolean`, by that I mean it'll return `1` if verified and nothing if not, as [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_var_is_array.asp) says

> This function returns true (1) if the variable is an array, otherwise
> it returns false/nothing.

So you might want to adjust your expected output from `TRUE` to `1` and `FALSE` to ''

```
$arr=[1,2];
switch (is_array($arr)) {
    case 1:
        print "yes";
        break;
    case '':
        print "no";
        break;
}
```

Comment: Only the first sentence and quote is correct here. `is_array()` [returns an actual boolean](https://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php). The reason your example still works is because PHP sees `1` as a truthy value and `''` as falsy. You can read more about [type juggling in PHP in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). I highly recommend you to stop reading (and referencing) w3schools. That site is infamous for being wrong and outdated.